# Invalid JSON file

Tags: php, json

I have a json file that contains following data. It is being detected as invalid json on http://jsonlint.com/ and hence being detected as string instead of json in php. Any suggestions on how to work around this issue in php? I cannot manually change every file as i have over thousand files.

```
{"contributors":null,"text":"@bru: i'll NEVER stop rollerblading! had a great dream last night that i was rollerblading while wearing a jetpack. must investigate...","geo":null,"retweeted":false,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"truncated":false,"entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[{"id":null,"name":null,"indices":[0,4],"screen_name":"@bru","id_str":null}]},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"id":1856693,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"web","favorited":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"retweet_count":0,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"created_at":"Sat Dec 30 12:47:22 +0000 2006","id_str":"1856693","place":null,"user":{"location":"Cambridge, UK","default_profile":false,"statuses_count":0,"profile_background_tile":true,"lang":"","profile_link_color":"78B0C8","id":12763,"following":false,"favourites_count":0,"protected":false,"profile_text_color":"000000","contributors_enabled":false,"description":"an infinitely hot and dense dot","verified":false,"name":"Rik Abel","profile_sidebar_border_color":"CDCDCD","profile_background_color":"FFFFFF","created_at":"Mon Jan 16 21:30:35 +0000 2006","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":0,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_image_url":"http://a1.twimg.com/images/themes/theme/bg.gif","follow_request_sent":false,"url":"http://www.rikabel.com","utc_offset":0,"time_zone":"London","notifications":null,"profile_use_background_image":true,"friends_count":0,"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"ffffff","screen_name":"rikabel","id_str":"12763","profile_image_url":"riksplit.jpg","show_all_inline_media":false,"is_translator":false,"listed_count":0}}
{"info":{"message":"Replay Request Completed","sent":"2013-12-24T03:19:36+00:00","activity_count":1}}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can programmatically correct all the files

Comment: you could start by finding out what is incorrect in the file.

Comment: Is this one or two JSON files?

Comment: You need a { before and a } after if its 2 lines as well as the comma separating

Comment: it seems to be two json files, you have to split it into to objects at `}{`, then parse them.

Comment: this is silly. you have 2 json objects concatenated one after the other in the same file. It does not make any sense to do that. Why would you do that ?

Comment: I have not created the json file. It is obtained from a data source. I am only trying to parse it. Anyway now that i know its two json objects, I will treat it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have two objects, the main json has to be an object or an array on its own.

```
Parse error on line 77:
...ed_count": 0    }}{    "info": {    
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

My favorite site for this type of problem (or just google validate json online)

http://jsonlint.com/

You will have to modify the string in php to get valid json.
If all the files you have consist of multiple objects perhaps you can wrap the list as an array.

```
$jsonToParse = '['. str_replace('}{', '},{', $jsonStringFromFile) .']';
```

Its not pretty but it should work.